# Lodash if else one line

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this forEach function that loops over a const object, but I want to do an if else in one line but I'm not sure how. This is how I'm doing it now.

```
const object = {
(Name ? (Name: _.get(object, 'abc'))), : (OtherName ? (OtherName: _.get(object, 'abc'))),
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you show sample input and the desired output?

Comment: As @Barmar says if you can show a few sample sets of values and what objects the should generate then it would make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want this, but you can use square brackets with a ternary operator to dynamically select the key:

```js
const _ = { get: (o,t) => "answer" } // mock lodash
const Name = null   // makes it choose OtherName (non-null for Name)
let object = null
object = { [Name ? "Name" : "OtherName"]: _.get(object, 'abc') }
console.log(object)

// or maybe this?
const OtherName = "something"
object = { Name: Name ? _.get(object, 'abc') : OtherName }
console.log(object)
```

Comment: I think `Name` and `OtherName` are both supposed to be variables, so I think it could just be `[ Name || OtherName ]`

Comment: possibly but it's really  not too clear - I may just delete  my answer until the question is clarified more

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Yea sorry i'm trying to clarify it more but it's a little difficult. Name and OtherName come from variables defined in a sequelize function. So when this populates MySQL database, it'll have Name and OtherName as columns. So I want it to populate Name with abc if it's Name, and OtherName if it's OtherName.

Comment: sorry - still not clear but does the code in the answer give you any guidance?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes it does provide some guidance. The issue is Name and OtherName are already defined from an import statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you want:

```
cons object = {
    [ Name || OtherName ]: _.get(object, 'abc')
};
```

If `Name` is not falsey it will be used as the property name, otherwise `OtherName` will be used.

Putting `[]` around the key of a property literal calculates the property name dynamically from the enclosed expression.